# Linux remove a occurrence of sentence from a file and add add start and end

Tags: awk, sed, curl, csv, xml

I have a script that **curl** a command to sms gateway to send sms and get xml as response. Each response are appended to a single file for future **xsltproc** process for creating csv.

A single response is like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1' ?><REPLY><PARAMETER>OK</PARAMETER><LOGIN>SUCCESSFULL</LOGIN><PUSHAPI>ACTIVE</PUSHAPI><STAKEHOLDERID>OK</STAKEHOLDERID><PERMITTED>OK</PERMITTED><SMSINFO><MSISDN>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</MSISDN><SMSTEXT>Test+SMS+Check</SMSTEXT><CSMSID>113426778</CSMSID><REFERENCEID>2020050321383271896124009</REFERENCEID></SMSINFO></REPLY>
```

Now each time the script runs it appends the same response with separate values with duplicate `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1' ?><REPLY>` and `</REPLY>`

so after 2nd time execution the file will be:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1' ?><REPLY><PARAMETER>OK</PARAMETER><LOGIN>SUCCESSFULL</LOGIN><PUSHAPI>ACTIVE</PUSHAPI><STAKEHOLDERID>OK</STAKEHOLDERID><PERMITTED>OK</PERMITTED><SMSINFO><MSISDN>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</MSISDN><SMSTEXT>Test+SMS+Check</SMSTEXT><CSMSID>113426778</CSMSID><REFERENCEID>2020050321383271896124009</REFERENCEID></SMSINFO></REPLY><?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1' ?><REPLY><PARAMETER>OK</PARAMETER><LOGIN>SUCCESSFULL</LOGIN><PUSHAPI>ACTIVE</PUSHAPI><STAKEHOLDERID>OK</STAKEHOLDERID><PERMITTED>OK</PERMITTED><SMSINFO><MSISDN>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</MSISDN><SMSTEXT>Test+SMS+Check</SMSTEXT><CSMSID>113426778</CSMSID><REFERENCEID>2020050321383271896124009</REFERENCEID></SMSINFO></REPLY>
```

which have 2 `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1' ?><REPLY>` and `</REPLY>`.

But **xsltproc** can not process multiple `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1' ?><REPLY>` and `</REPLY>`

So I need to remove all `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1' ?><REPLY>` and `</REPLY>` and just keep or add a `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1' ?><REPLY>` at beginning of file and `</REPLY>` end of file while final processing.

So my file while processing for **xsltproc** after 2nd run should be like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1' ?><REPLY><PARAMETER>OK</PARAMETER><LOGIN>SUCCESSFULL</LOGIN><PUSHAPI>ACTIVE</PUSHAPI><STAKEHOLDERID>OK</STAKEHOLDERID><PERMITTED>OK</PERMITTED><SMSINFO><MSISDN>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</MSISDN><SMSTEXT>Test+SMS+Check</SMSTEXT><CSMSID>113426778</CSMSID><REFERENCEID>2020050321383271896124009</REFERENCEID></SMSINFO><PARAMETER>OK</PARAMETER><LOGIN>SUCCESSFULL</LOGIN><PUSHAPI>ACTIVE</PUSHAPI><STAKEHOLDERID>OK</STAKEHOLDERID><PERMITTED>OK</PERMITTED><SMSINFO><MSISDN>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</MSISDN><SMSTEXT>Test+SMS+Check</SMSTEXT><CSMSID>113426778</CSMSID><REFERENCEID>2020050321383271896124009</REFERENCEID></SMSINFO></REPLY>
```

So how to remove all `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1' ?><REPLY>` except the first one in the file and remove all `</REPLY>` except the last one.

Or is there any other way to create the csv or xlx for record.

Comment: Your problem seems to be here: _each time the script runs it appends the same response with separate values with duplicate xml_ It might be a good idea to share that part of the script at least, to add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed, it will start as simple as

```
sed 's/...//g2' file
```

In GNU sed, asking for a `general` (`g`) substitution followed by a number means that all the repetitions **starting** with the number will be replaced.

```
sed 's@<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1' ?><REPLY>@@g2' file
```

Of course that doesn't change the `</REPLY>` tags, this would:

```
sed 's@</REPLY>@@g' file; echo '</REPLY>' >> file
```